# How to turn off (=make black) certain pixels on a screen?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

A relatively expensive screen I have broke - when two or three pixels in the middle of the screen get white, the entire screen starts to flicker and is unusable.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make (=instruct) certain pixels on the screen black to be, so this doesn't happen anymore? I'm using following systems:

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Windows 7

My graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce GTX 670.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've got it backwards. The pixels themselves can't be "broke". When a pixel cluster (triad) has all three spots turned on 100%, that is 100% red+green+blue and it makes the pixel cluster appear to be white.

The graphics controller circuitry is failing, and sending full power to all three spots, so the pixels appear to be white. But the pixel is just faithfully doing what the controller circuitry is telling it to do.

And that same failing circuitry is probably telling the whole screen to flicker--because the controller is failing. Could be a loose connection, could be a defective chip, but this is normally a hardware failure and indicates a complete video failure is to come. You might want to back up your system, while you still can read the display to do that. And then get it to a tech for hardware diagnosis.

There's no way that you can "turn off these pixels" from the user level. Only the video controller hardware can do that, and you can't program that.

When there is a physical display fault, pixels usually go black, because they are dead/disconnected. White means something is turning them on. If this is an older laptop, the answer is often to cannibalize the display parts from another donor machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a defect on your screen ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_pixel )

To confirm this, unplug your computer and bring up the OSD menu (to select input for example). You should see the defectives pixels.

You cannot fix this from the computer side.

Comment: I'm aware that it's a broken pixel. It wouldn't bother me much, wouldn't the entire screen start to flicker when this broken pixel is instructed to display white. So what I'm asking for is to instruct the pixel to be black - it will still be visible afterwards, but at least the rest of the screen will be fine.